# Flutter: How to perform an actions after Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil() has completed

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

In my Flutter app, I need to clear the Navigator stack and get back to the Home page when a certain button is pressed. To achieve that I've used `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context, "/", (r) => false);`. I also need to call a function after the navigation has been completed, meaning that I'm now on the Home page.

I've tried calling the `.whenComplete()` method on `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()`, but it doesn't seem to work.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting an error when you call your function inside `whenComplete` method?

Comment: Nope. The `whenComplete()` method simply doesn't get called. I've just checked the docs and found out the reason why. _Returns a Future that completes to the result value passed to pop when the pushed route is popped off the navigator._ (talking about `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say use your function inside `dipose()`, so it's called when the widget is removed from the tree as you navigate to another screen.

```
class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  
  // ...
  // Some code
  
  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Insert your function here
    super.dispose();
  }
  
  // ...
}
```

### Using `didPush()` method

This can be used to call your function after navigating to another screen because it returns when the push transition is complete. However, you have to do it with `pushAndRemoveUntil()` instead of `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()`. So, you can create a `PageRoute` which provides `didPush()` method.

```
// Create your route
MaterialPageRoute route = MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => HomePage(),
);
// Push the route onto the navigator, and then remove all the previous routes
Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(context, route, (r) => false);
// This returns when the push transition is complete.
route.didPush().whenComplete(() {
  // Insert your function here
});
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve my issue because the function would get called every time I exit that page. I only need to call the function when the button is pressed.

Comment: Can you try the alternative way that I just added?

Comment: I got this error message: _Unhandled Exception: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
E/flutter (25278): At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
E/flutter (25278): To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method._

Comment: This is probably because you tried to access the context that isn't available inside `whenComplete()`. Don't forget that this widget will be removed from the three when `didPush()` is complete and you can't use the context that is associated with it.

Comment: Makes sense... And how would I fix this?

Comment: I can't know that before seeing your code, but I can give you a tip. Whatever you do with context, do it before calling the navigator.

Comment: This means that if I were to need to access the context after calling the Navigator, this solution would not be viable, right?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do with the context. Are you displaying a SnackBar or accessing a provider? Let's say you want to access a provider using the context. You'll do `final provider = Provider.of<DBProvider>(context);` before the navigator and use it inside `whenComplete()` like this: `provider.fetchItems();`. This will work for sure, but you can't do this: `Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar());`.

Comment: I do want to access a provider. I've tried exactly what you've suggested, but I've got this error message: _MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>.didPush called before calling install() or after calling dispose().
'package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart':
Failed assertion: line 213 pos 12: '_controller != null'_

Comment: Actually, there might be something wrong with the flutter framework itself, since this is what followed the error message: _Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:_

Comment: It's hard to say something in this way. If you add your code to the question,  maybe we could figure out why you see the error.

Comment: Nevermind, I've managed to solve the issue that had lead to my question in a totally different way. Still, thank you very much for the helpful tips.

Answer (score -1):

You can try as well as this code And please let me know.

```
gotoNewPage(context) async {
  await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) =>
              NewPage()));

/// Your logic is here.
}
```

Comment: I've tried it and, unfortunately, it doesn't work. It looks like the Navigator.push() is awaited forever because any line of code written afterwards doesn't get executed. I've tried with a 'print()' after your code and nothing gets printed.

Comment: this won't work as a push future will be completed when we close the page only